# Custom colormar range in Matlab using negative and floating point

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colormap

I'm tryng to set a hot colormap to a image loaded from floating point data that range from -1.56 to 310.24.

Sample code:

```
imshow(myData);
colormap(hot); % nothing is changed, it keeps using a greyscale-like colormap.
colorbar();
```

I know I can normalize the data from 0 to 255, but this way the colorbar will not be representative of the actual data values anymore. So, is there any better way that I can achieve that?

Edit:

I noticed that imshow(myData,'Colormap',hot,'DisplayRange',[minV maxV] do the work, but I don't know why I can't change the colormap using colormap(hot) after imshow.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the range when calling `imshow` changing the colormap should work, and the associated colorbar should display the correct range:

```
imshow(myData,[-1.56 310.24]);
colormap(hot);
colorbar;
```

Edit:
Since this does not seem to work for you, I would suggest using the function `imagesc` instead, which seems to behave in a more consistent matter:

```
imagesc(myData);
colormap(hot);
colorbar;
```

The range of data is selected automatically, but you can still set it by hand if needed:

```
caxis([-1.56 310.24]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, colormap won't change. See my edit.

Comment: That is strange, it works for me.
Do you have to use imshow? I would suggest using imagesc instead.